# Python 2.7 override the entire class definition in a different module

Tags: python

I would like to override the functionality of a class (installed in a system directory)

```
module a
class A:
   ...
```

with (my local class)

```
module b
class B:
   ...
```

entirely, that is override all the methods that are common to `A` and `B` with those in `B`. There have been questions similar to this

[Python - how can I override the functionality of a class before it's imported by a different module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794905/python-how-can-i-override-the-functionality-of-a-class-before-its-imported-by)

however they override a single (or several methods).

**Q1:** I guess I could go over all of the methods if `class A` and find the counterpart in `class B`, but is there a cleaner way of doing this?

My attempts to override the entire class definition hasn't worked so far, so either I am not doing it correctly or this is not possible.

**Q2:** I suppose the override has to occur before any other module tries to import the `module a`?

**Why am I doing this**

I need to change behaviour of instances of class A in code that I can't easily change

**Setup**

I have a bunch of modules that `from a import A` (which I cannot easily change) and later call methods of `A`:

```
#module c
from a import A

a_instance_global = A()

def some_function()
    a_instance = a()
    a_instance.somemethod()
```

In every one of them I would like to mock `A` with `B` without changing the code of installed modules.

```
#module d (module that I can change)
from c import some_function

# I would like to say something like a.A = b.B
# which works, however the override stays valid only in module d
# and I would like to have the override to work in module c
some_function()

a_instance_global.call_something()

some_other_function(a_instance_global):
   ...
```

Comment: You mean, you still want to use, some methods in A, but want to modify some other methods of A.

Comment: @pnv yes, this is what i meant

Comment: @iggy Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @MJeffryes I am doing a mocked run of a certain module (written by someone else) and I would like to override that modules behaviour and not change their sources.

Comment: @iggy OK, I'm just curious why subclassing isn't sufficient for your needs.

Comment: @MJeffryes instantiations of `class A` are scattered in code of modules that `import module a` and I want any instantiation of `"A"` to use `class B` instead

Comment: @iggy I don't know whether you've looked at [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock) yet, but it seems like you could accomplish it with that. Specifically the patch decorator.

Comment: @MJeffryes `unittest.mock` would be nice but I am using `python 2.7`

Comment: @iggy I believe that `unittest.mock` is available as a third party package for python<3. (It was included in the stdlib afterwards). So you can still install that package and use it in all python versions. Moreover, if the `a` module references the `A` class only inside functions and none of these is executed before you mock it then nneonneo very simple solution will work perfectly well.  If it doesn't work is because these assumptions aren't valid.

Comment: Yes [it is](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way:

```
import a
class A: # replacement A
    ...

a.A = A
```

The only caveat here is that you have to do this override before any other module creates an instance of `A`; otherwise, those instances will reference the old class definition.

If you can't do this replacement before instances are created, you'll have to settle for patching each of the class methods yourself.

Comment: would this work if `module a` is installed in a system directory? I am doing in exactly this way but it doesn't work

Comment: actually your solution works, but only inside the module that I override. When I `import module a` in other modules (not where I called the override) the definition of `A` is the same.

Comment: your solution works. I was doing something wrong, I the class `A` was imported by some other module before the override

Answer (score 2):

If I got your question right, the scenario is

file -> A_module.py (Original A class resides here)

```
class A(object):
    def one(self):
        print "A -> one"
    def two(self):
        print "A -> two"
    def three(self):
        print "A -> three"
```

file -> module_where_a_is_used.py (You want changes here.)

```
from A_module import A

def lol_function():
    a_object = A()
    a_object.three()
    a_object.one()
```

The solution would be, make a module -> A_module_class_modifier.py
Taking an idea (rather copying :P) from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794905/python-how-can-i-override-the-functionality-of-a-class-before-its-imported-by)

```
import A_module
from A_module import A

class B(A):
    def one(self):
        print "B -> one"
    def two(self):
        print "B -> two"

A_module.A = B
```

Now, your module_where_a_is_used.py should be intact (A.K.A. C module),

```
from A_module import A

def lol_function():
    a_object = A()
    a_object.three()
    a_object.one()
```

lol.py

```
import A_module_class_modifier
from module_where_a_is_used import lol_function

lol_function()
```

Result after running lol.py

```
I have no name!@sla-334:~/stack_o/stack_o_class$ python lol.py 
A -> three
B -> one
```

I hope, I got that right, if not please tell me, what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: yes, the setup is correct. However it will require calling `change_A` in every module I would like to use mocked `class A`

Comment: Check out new solution, @Iggy

Comment: from what I understand your second solution requires to change the installed `module c` (see the setup in the question), which I cannot do

Comment: Now, you've to import `import A_module_class_modifier`, in D.py  , C.py no longer needs modification

Comment: but this wouldn't override `A` in `module c`

Comment: Of course it would, because `A_module.A = B`, would change `A`!

Comment: as I said, the override only has effect in modules where you said `a.A = B` (by using statement `import A_module_class_modifier` in your case) , but this need to modify `module c` (which I explicitly said I cannot change)

Comment: Please, kindly, read the entire answer again (with discarding earlier discussion from your mind), I'm not changing your `C module`!

Comment: I guess you don't get the point. You are overriding `A` with `B` in  `lol.py` by means of `import A_module_class_modifier` (first of all, this has effect only in `lol.py` and not "globally"). You have to actually change every file and add this line if you want the override to have effect. Well, as I said, I can't do that!

Comment: What project is it? When your project starts, configure it such that `A_module_class_modifier`, is run first then, it'll have effect. In that case, you don't have to add `import A_module_class_modifier`, everywhere.

Comment: If it's a django project, refer to http://eldarion.com/blog/2013/02/14/entry-point-hook-django-projects/

Answer (score 1):

As for Q2, yes, I don't think there is a way around that unless you find all instances of that class that were created after `A` was imported (but before changing `A` in `a` to `B` and update them.

As for Q1, the dirty method  by importing `sys` and inserting the module `b` in place of `a`:

```
import sys
sys.modules['a'] = sys.modules['b']
```

after that has been executed, any import or refrence to 'a' will effectively be to `b`. If in addition in `b` you have:

```
A = B
```

then creating an instance of class `A` will effectively create a `B` This applies for all instance created after the `sys.modules` line has been executed, whether the import of the module `a` was before or after that.

Comment: this seems promising. Can I substitute class definitions in this way and not entire modules?

Comment: > then creating an instance of class A will effectively create a B. < This won't work if name A already was import like `from a import A` -- a reference to the original class has already been created.